# Import problems in eclipse

Tags: java

Consider the following steps than I've taken:

1. I created a new java project, named 'A' in my eclipse work space.
2. I created a new class named 'Class1' and mentioned no package name for it. So it was created in the default package.
3. I created a new package named 'somepackage' and created a new class named 'class2' in this package.

Now I need to import class1 in class2, and use its features and services. But whatever I do I can't do this. What is the way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Put your `Class1` into a package.

Comment: First, put them into package, this is strongly recommended. Then you can focus to that Class1 and Ctrl Shift M to import

Comment: Keep Class1 in some package.and import it.otherwise you can't

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your Class1 in a package other than default package in order to import it or you can use reflection to use it from default package.

Comment: You mean isn't there any way that does not require me to edit the code of class1?

Comment: You can use reflection as mentioned in answer

Comment: What do you mean exactly by reflection?

Comment: [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)